# How to set namespace when you create a new library or project?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, namespaces, project

Imagine that you want to create a new algorithms library.

For instance:

```
namespace Com.MyCompanyName.LibraryPathfinding 
{
//...
}
```

Another one could import this library (include namespace) and use it.

For instance:

```
using Com.MyCompanyName.LibraryPathfinding

namespace Com.YourCompanyName.ProjectX
{
//...
//ProjectX is a game
}
```

My question is:

If LibraryPathfinding use some kinds of util class which like "PriorityQueue", how to set PriorityQueue's namespace?

(1):

```
namespace Com.MyCompanyName.LibraryPathfinding.Collections
{
    public class PriorityQueue 
    {
       ////
    }
}
```

(2) :

```
namespace Com.MyCompanyName.Collections
{
     public class PriorityQueue
     {
       ////
     }
}
```

If choose (1), it means PriorityQueue is a part of LibraryPathfinding.

The advantage of this is:

LibraryPathfinding is completely independent.

If your project need pathfinding, just import "Com.MyCompanyName.LibraryPathfinding"

The disadvantage of this is:

Whenever your project need PriorityQueue, you must import "Com.MyCompanyName.LibraryPathfinding", even though ProjectX don't need Pathfinding.

For instance:
In ProjectX, AIManager need a aggro list which use priority queue.
But aggro list shouldn't dependent on Pathfinding!

If choose (2), it could resolve (1)'s problem.

The disadvantage of this is:

LibraryPathfinding will be not completely independent. (LibraryPathfinding  is a encapsulation and it shouldn't expose implement detail.)

If you want to use LibraryPathfinding, you must import Com.MyCompanyName.Collections and Com.MyCompanyName.LibraryPathfinding. This means: you must release two libraries (to your user)!

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A single assembly can contain multiple namespaces, and namespaces can be defined across multiple assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you want to use LibraryPathfinding, you must import Com.MyCompanyName.Collections and Com.MyCompanyName.LibraryPathfinding. This means: you must release two libraries!*

That's often the behavior that you *want* to have. If "PriorityQueue" is a class you may want to reuse in a project in the future, you should isolate it into a new project - grouped along with any other relevant classes. Code reuse is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for replay. But LibraryPathfinding is a encapsulation, it shouldn't expose implement detail. PriorityQueue is a implement detail, is it right? There is no any public interface in LibraryPathfinding (which like get a queue from LibraryPathfinding), PriorityQueue is only used in LibraryPathfinding's astar algorithms internally!

Comment: I wass assuming that "PriorityQueue" is a utility class you may like to reuse elsewhere. Consider the .Net frameworks "Queue<T>" class. It resides in System.Collections.Generic. If you have a "utility" project containing your own collection objects that will often come in useful in other solutions. I'm not sure I follow the comment about encapsulation. If the PriorityQueue is not generic enough for reuse, it should just reside with LibraryPathfinding.